# Рассчитать и вывести отклонение точек от модели

Tags: python, регрессия

Есть данные по ежегодным измерениям в фиксированных точках [таблица](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DUXb9iJdIVWRp0iUjWgVlPru1tG4frt7/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105326785031219603112&rtpof=true&sd=true).

Период с 1980х по н.в. с пропусками некоторых лет, точек измерений 925, но в некоторые годы есть точки без измерений.

Создал корреляционную матрицу по годам и оставил ячейки с R > 0,7.

```
acc = pd.read_excel('111.xlsx').round()
acc = acc.set_index('point')
acc = acc.corr().round(2)
acc = acc[(acc < -0.7 ) | (acc > 0.7) & (acc != 1)]
matrix = np.triu(acc)
plt.figure(figsize = (21,12), dpi = 100)
sns.heatmap(acc, center = 0.55, cmap = 'Blues',
    annot = True, cbar= False, linewidth=.5, linecolor = 'black', mask=(matrix))
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод координат ячеек и значений R из матрицы:

```
 acc = acc.abs().unstack().dropna(axis = 0).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Выводятся 268 ячеек, хотя из-за mask в sns.heatmap в матрице их показана половина - 134.

Как для каждой заданной пары лет с R > 0,7 вывести уравнение регрессии и отклонение от модели для каждой точки измерений?

Под моделью имею в виду линейную регрессию. Пример графика для 1998 и 2001 годов.

```
def regr(x, y):
   x = acc[x]
   y = acc[y]
   sns.regplot(x, y)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытка найти отклонение через OLS c таким кодом и подстановкой лет без пропусков в данных (2020 - 2023 годы) проходит.

```
def regr(x, y):
    x = acc[x]
    y = acc[y]
    x = sm.add_constant (x)
    model = sm. OLS (y, x). fit ()
    print(model. summary ())
    res = model. resid
    print(res)
regr(2022,2023)
```

Если в regr() подставить годы с пропусками, то появляется ошибка "MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans". Как в этом случае выкинуть из расчетов точку с пропусками?

Comment: В смысле числами вывести то, что вам рисует графиком `regplot`? Ну можете обычную линейную регрессию https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html зафитить на этих `x` и `y` и посмотреть коэффициенты `.coef_` у неё. Ну и потом посмотреть разницу имеющихся точек `(x, y)` и что даёт в качестве `y` регрессия при предсказании на `x`. Если нужно это и непонятно как сделать, могу в ответе расписать. Если нужно что-то другое - пишите. Но вообще там всё просто по идее. `regplot` по идее ту же стандартную линейную регрессию использует.

Comment: да, нужно это и прошу помощи с кодом

Comment: самая большая проблема - отсутствие одного или пары значений для каждой точки, вылезает ошибка: MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans. как я понимаю, надо удалить точки с пропусками

Comment: Может быть. То есть какой-то ещё код у вас есть или это на этом коде из вопроса такая ошибка выходит? Если есть ещё код - добавьте в вопрос. Я позже посмотрю и может свой код напишу, может даже завтра, как время будет.

Comment: Да, код добавил

Comment: Так, ну точки то можно выкинуть, только, например `acc[[2022,2023]]` состоит из одних только `NaN`, цифр там вообще нет.

Comment: Это из-за вашего условия, что абсолютное значение корреляции должно быть больше 7, но меньше 1. Вы вообще уверены, что вам нужно регрессию именно по коэффициентам корреляции строить, а не по исходным значениям датасета?

Comment: Вообще подходящих сочетаний годов будет `268` штук. Вы уверены, что вам нужно `268` регрессий строить? Лучше приведите формулировку исходной задачи. Сейчас это что-то странное. )

Comment: 1. про выкинуть точки, например, при анализе 2000 и 2020 г.: если есть пропуск данных у точки Н в 2000 году, то убрать из анализа эту точку вовсе, при этом может быть несколько таких пар с пропусками. Как прописать, чтобы алгоритм пропускал в регрессии пары с NaN (тогда наверное перестанет вылезать NaN-ошибка)?

Comment: 2. 1>R>0,7 - это фильтр, корреляцию строю по исходным (полевым) данным. 3. подходящих сочетаний не 268, а в половину меньше 134 из-за исключения дублирования (a,b) и (b,a). Код для вывода всех 268 ячеек добавил под первую картинку, хотя потом вручную удалял дубляжи)). Как вывести отклонения 134 регрессий в одну таблицу параллельными столбцами?